# How to simulate an exhaust fan condition in ANSYS Fluent?

Tags: simulation, cfd, ansys-workbench, fluent

I'm trying to simulate a model which has one inlet and three outlets, and I'm passing air through it. Now, I want one of the outlets to have exhaust fan. I see options of exhaust fan and outlet-vent in the boundary conditions. So how should I simulate for this condition? And previously, I had done the simulation with all the three outlets which were given the outflow factors as 0.4,0.3&0.3, and the case I'm referring to, what outflow factor I need to give and simulate while one being used as exhaust fan/ outlet vent and the rest being the regular outflows?